# How to iterate a List and print it's content one by one in each groupFooter?

Tags: list, jasper-reports

I just want to know, is there any way to iterate a List and print it's content one by one (incremental) in each groupFooter?

I create a group in my report, and in each groupFooter section, I want to display content from a `java.util.List` I sent from Java class via parameter.

Currently I just using `jr:list` and `jr:listContents` in my groupFooter, and the result is **all contents** from the list is printed in **every groupFooter**. I got an headache to solve this, so any help will relief me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should try to iterate the List to get content in a certain number of `groupFooter`, instead I would get content directly List based on index.

What we need is simple a pointer (position in list), in your case this number seems to be an incremented number every time we have a new group.

A variabile counting as group change is:

```
<variable name="countMyGroup" class="java.lang.Integer" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="Group1" calculation="Count">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[""]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

With this simple variabile we will now have the current number of group that is displayed and we can add a `textField` with the value from or `List` using this number. see [`java.util.List.get(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-)

```
<parameter name="listOfStuff" class="java.util.List" isForPrompting="false"/>
.....
<textField>
    <reportElement x="120" y="0" width="267" height="17" uuid="b45699d3-5d34-4d88-b7bc-2666cf787ace">
    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{listOfStuff}.size()>=$V{countMyGroup}]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{listOfStuff}.get($V{countMyGroup}-1)]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

> Note: the `printWhenExpression` will avoid `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, hence that the group number is higher then the size of our `List`

**Full jrxml example**, it use a dummy group changing on each record, to try it use a `JREmptyDatasource` with a couple of records.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ListOnEachPage" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="33394f25-66fc-431b-ac82-88660e9115e5">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Empty 4 records"/>
    <parameter name="listOfStuff" class="java.util.List" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[Arrays.asList(new String[]{"group 1","group 2","group 3"})]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <variable name="countMyGroup" class="java.lang.Integer" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="Group1" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[""]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="Group1">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="34">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="120" y="0" width="267" height="17" uuid="b45699d3-5d34-4d88-b7bc-2666cf787ace">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{listOfStuff}.size()>=$V{countMyGroup}]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{listOfStuff}.get($V{countMyGroup}-1)]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="445" y="0" width="100" height="17" uuid="e5c46332-b137-4c55-99e4-265c87b8f97d"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{countMyGroup}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <detail>
        <band height="63" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="140" y="20" width="264" height="30" uuid="1ec9f950-dd2d-4c18-a81a-b0da937eb1b5"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Just some text to simulate detail band]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**Output**, see how values from list are extracted as long as we are within size of List

[image: output]

Comment: I don't know why, but in my .jrxml, it should be `$P{listOfStuff}.get($V{countMyGroup}-2)` not `-1`. Else was just perfection, perfection, perfection, thanks :)

Comment: @Hobas What is your initialValueExpression in variabile?

Comment: It's the same as your example

Comment: Yeah that's strange since group count start at 1 and List at 0, you need to debug some to understand why

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a variable which increment at your group level.
Step 2 its to use that variable in a simple textfield or what component you want (not a collection component) and put his expression like this : list.indexOf(countVariable)

Comment: Thanks for answered my question, your answer actually spot-on as well :)